# Ckeditor loads first time after instanceCreated, after reload the page ckeditor is undefined

Tags: ckeditor

In the site a have two pages, in one ckeditor works normally, on the other one it`s undefined, and begins to work in`CKEDITOR.on('instanceCreated', function(e) {` but after the page is reloaded it again became -  undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the site also is used a lightbox script, when I put the string which calls the ckeditor: ckeditor.js higher then lightbox.js  - all became good!